Absolute positioned element slightly off-center in div
I've seen other questions asking about why there centered div is slightly off-center, but this is different. Questions are saying to set padding to 0, but it isn't working, and I think it could be due to the absolute position. A few other things i tried here
Does anyone know why this would be happening? I'm using an absolute-positioned dot in a flexbox.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .slider {
      width: 20px;
      height: 100px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      position: relative;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 2cqw;
    }
    
    .line {
      border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }
    
    .selector {
      background-color: black;
      border-radius: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="selector"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>




Looks pretty centered to me with the provided snippet?

@DarkBee it seems perhaps a tiny bit out to me on the left for example, depending on zoom level this comes and goes. I suspect this is inevitable, different 'rounding' errors when the system is trying to match CSS pixels to multiple screen pixels and create the curve. Sometimes a screen pixel may be dropped for example.

As of Chrome v126.0 this is centered at any zoom level

@AHaworth Thanks for the info, I'll probably take a cheap solution and translatex it slightly.

@Symtox I think that depends on both the version of browser and the type of screen you are using. For me on 126 the circle is very slightly off center on normal zoom, and comes and goes on and off center with zooming.

@SojoBee translating x slightly may well solve it for some screens, but probably not all!

Btw is it legal to use cqw when no container-type is defined ?

@Symtox yeah idk why i used that. probably just to mess with people :|

we have modified the CSS code. Please use this
.slider {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2cqw;

    /* Added this style with center */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.line {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.selector {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


Sorry, this dosen't do anything with my objective. I'm trying to center the .selector, not the .slider. And it's not perfectly centered. @AHaworth did an explanation why this is happening.

Sure, I am trying CSS code modification as per the comments, Thanks for quick response

Please explain what you've actually changed and how this addresses the actual issue. Code-only answers are not good answers.
