Element attaching to the bottom of container
I'm trying to center a dot inside a div. When I try margin-bottom: 50%;, it pushes the other stuff around. I've also tried setting justify-content and align-items to center.


.slider{
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;a
    position: relative;

    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.line{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.selector{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
<div class="slider">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="selector"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>




What should this look like and how is it different from your previous question? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78781682/absolute-positioned-element-slightly-off-center-in-div

Your "line" div has no height, you can't center something in nothing.

@Paulie_D Yes, but if I add a height, then the lines won't dynamically size to fit. I am a beginner though, please tell me if I'm wrong. My previous question is different. This time, I'm trying a new approach where I'm putting the selector inside the line. That way it can be coded easier with js. But I can't figure out how to center it.

selector inside the line nonsense. your line is Zero pixel height, with only a border bottom of two pixels.

@MisterJojo Sorry I'm a begginer, Lajos Arpad explained in the answer below that you can use 100% to evenly space them instead. Thanks for correcting me though!

You can set the height to 100% for line and margin: auto for the dot:
.line{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.selector{
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}



.slider{
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;a
    position: relative;

    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
.line{
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
.line:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.selector{
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}
<div class="slider">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="selector"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
</div>




Make sure to remove the border for the last child: .line:not(:last-child) {border-bottom;}

@SojoBee thanks for the comment. If this answer solves the problem, then it might be accepted as the correct answer.

You can eliminate the .line divs entirely, div element should be for content, not styling.
Just use a repeating-linear-gradient to create the lines and then center as usual.
Here I have added red lines at the horizontal and vertical centers to show the centered element.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  margin: 1em;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  background: linear-gradient(black 0.1em, transparent 0.1em);
  background-size: 100% 20px;
  /* 100px / 5 */
  background-position: 0 -2px;
  /* adjust for border size */
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.selector {
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
  background: black;
}


/* demo only */

.slider:before {
  /* horizontal line */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50%;
  translate: 0 -50%;
}

.slider:after {
  /* vertical line */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: red;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  translate: -50%
}
<div class="slider">

  <div class="selector"></div>

</div>



